# How do game/game engine debug consoles work?

Tags: architecture, game-engine, command-pattern

**I posted this question before hand on gamedev exchange but it got flagged as off-topic. I'm not sure how to edit the question to make it more on topic so I though maybe it would be best here? The question has been pasted as-is below. I am not trying to spark discussion. Let me know how to improve this question if you've any suggestions.**

I'm developing a 3D scene renderer using OpenGL and a debug console is something I would really like to implement for a couple of reasons:

I think it would help in development so the earlier it's implemented the better.It seems like a really interesting and powerful feature to know how to implement.

I have had trouble finding much good material on how such consoles work and I apologise as this is most likely down to poor google-fu. I did find this question which seemed quite relevant however but - and I could very well be wrong - I'm not sure it's discussing quite what I am looking for. I'm looking to create a console which is quite powerful in that it can execute commands with parameters such that commands might have multiple levels of depth, for example the following commands might exist:

- [camera set pos] : Resets camera position to 0,0,0.
- [camera set pos -3 2 5.5] : Sets camera position to -3,2,5.5.
- [camera set clip 0.1 1000] : Sets camera near-clip to 0.1 and far-clip to 1000.
- [camera set clip far 1024] : Sets camera far-clip to 1024.
- [new object ] : Adds a new object to the scene, not sure how the user should enter properties and component properties though as the list of these would be of variable length. For example the user might just append a position and have the default object added to the scene, or they might go as far as to specify a mesh, texture, shader, etc.
- [new light 3 2 1 0 255 0] : Adds a green light to the scene at 3,2,1. Obviously lights would have a few more properties.
- [new light 3 2 1 purple] : Adds a purple light to the scene at 3,2,1.
- [object  set texture fancy_image.png] : Sets the texture of the object in the scene's list of objects with the name "objectname" to "fancy_image.png".

Sorry for the long list of commands; I wanted to give a thorough idea of the types of commands I'm interested in and the kind of power I would want such a console to have. Something else I am unsure about is whether this should even be an engine feature or a game-specific feature? Or is that irrelevant? I have studied the command pattern briefly on my University course but it seemed quite rigid and not flexible enough for the type of system I'm looking for. Have I simply and utterly misunderstood?

Any help here is appreciated and thanks is given in advance.

Comment: Thanks. I did. I would appreciate it if someone could help me edit it or explain specifically why it is off-topic. There is a small help center section relevant to the r

Comment: Sorry I am on mobile and my butter fingers posted too early! I was going to say there is a small relevant help center section but it does not provide much help to me. "Consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement if you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope." So I guess a more direct question might be how is it out of scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically asking how to build a command-line interface, which is, more or less, the same as asking how to build a parser.

The first step should be to build a class (or perhaps function, if you are working in that paradigm) for each command you want to support. For example:

```
public class SetCameraPositionCommand extends Command {

    float x;
    float y;
    float z;

    // etc...
}
```

You then need to design a function that applies the command to your game state. I won't go into the implementation here, but the signature might be like this:

```
void applyCommand(GameState gameState, Command command);
```

Once you have that working, it's time to write your parser. There are lots of ways to do this, but I would suggest *starting* with something hand-written, and very basic.

For example:

```
Command parseCommand(string input) {
  const args = input.split(' ')
    .map(x => x.trim().toLowerCase())
    .filter(x => x.length > 0);

  if (args.length == 2 && args[0] == 'camera' && args[1] == 'reset') {
    return new ResetCameraCommand();
  }

  // etc... 

  return null;
}
```

You should be able to see how this could be written in a cleaner fashion.

Writing unit-tests for the parser should be trivial.

Comment: I see, thank you. I think more than anything this question has made me realise I am struggling with the execution stage and how to go about that in a clean robust way. Does having this system mean I am going to have to make a lot of things publicly modifiable? I know you said you won't go in to the implementation, but have you any suggestions of where to look for more help on writing such functionality? Very helpful, thanks.

Comment: You have a few options. 1) The GameState class takes a Command and decides what to do with it. 2) The Command class takes a GameState and modifies it; the GameState must expose all properties required for this. 3) You make GameState immutable and fully public. The Command class returns a *new* GameState, rather than modifying it. This is the functional approach

Comment: I think option 1 sounds like a good start. Is the GameState class common practice? I've never had a GameState class in any of my projects (I think). Is it simply a class which stores instances of a games systems and properties?

Comment: A GameState class is a common practice. It would contains the entire state of the game, such as player positions, world objects, scores, etc.

Comment: Okay I feel a lot better about tackling this. Much appreciated. Thanks for actually trying to help me out as apposed to voting me off topic :)